# Does MonoTouch have CGRectGetMaxX and CGRectGetMaxY?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to place 2 UILabel's right next to each other... Where the first one end the other must start... In Xcode, Obj C I can use CGRectGetMaxX and CGRectGetMaxY... Does Monotouch have these functions since I can't find them at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UILabel.Frame got the 4 properties:

- .Bottom
- .Top
- .Left
- .Right

So you can get the coordinates to place the UILabels right next to each other pretty easy, by combining them.